# Is there a way to merge this 2?

Tags: java

I'm running out of idea of how will I merge this 2 conditions, it has the same return so I need to merge

```
if ((StringUtils.isBlank(ext))) {
    return true;
}

for (String str : INVALID_EXTENSION_ARR) {
    if (ext.matches(str)) {
        return true;
    } else if (ext.matches(str.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which conditions? The ones in the loop or the one before the loop with the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop.

Populate `INVALID_EXTENSION_ARR` with values in lowercase:

```
private static final List<String> INVALID_EXTENSION_ARR = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "whatever"); // Note: All in lowercase!
```

Then it's just one line:

```
return StringUtils.isBlank(ext) || INVALID_EXTENSION_ARR.contains(ext.toLowerCase());
```

**Note:** I have assumed when you used `matches()` you meant to use `equals()`.

——-

If the list of acceptable extensions is “large” (say, more than 10), you’ll get better performance if you use a Set instead of a List:

```
private static final Set<String> INVALID_EXTENSION_ARR = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "whatever"));
```

Or for recent java versions:

```
private static final Set<String> INVALID_EXTENSION_ARR = Set.of("foo", "bar", "whatever");
```

But you would be unlikely to *notice* much difference unless the size was more than say 100.

Comment: ARRAY don't have `.contains` function I don't think it will work xd

Comment: @ruakh. Do you know what `contains` does in this case?

Comment: @JúlzOrienza it’s a List, not an array.

Comment: @JúlzOrienza. That's why you should use a list instead, as shown here.

Comment: @ruakh I assumed that OP is inexperienced and meant `equals()` which makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the loop will always be entered into,

```
for (String str : INVALID_EXTENSION_ARR) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ext) || ext.matches(str)) {
        return true;
    } else if (ext.matches(str.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

but I think that way that had it was easier to read and does not need to re-evaluate `StringUtils.isBlank(ext)` every time.

Comment: yes I only need to evaluate `StringUtils.isBlank(ext)` once xd

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful if you provide more context, but this is one of the ways you can compact it.

```
for (String str : INVALID_EXTENSION_ARR) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ext) || ext.toLowerCase().matches(str.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }
}
```